# Как выводить спец. символы такими какие они есть

Tags: php

Есть строка:

`ЗП: 10 000₽ &#x2F; месяц (возможно повышение)`

мне нужно записать ее в базу в таком виде

> ЗП: 10 000₽ / месяц (возможно повышение)

Как это сделать?

Comment: Почему бы не использовать просто слеш?

Comment: @fixer мне приходит такая строка, и мне нужно ее преобразовать

Comment: Откуда такая строка приходит? И почему не могут отправить нормальную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте **[html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.html-entity-decode.php)** для преобразования HTML-сущности в соответствующие им символы.

```
echo html_entity_decode('ЗП: 10 000₽ &#x2F; месяц (возможно повышение)');
// ЗП: 10 000₽ / месяц (возможно повышение)
```